# Slack bot - prevent bot from replying to each incoming webhook

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, slack

I made a Slack command that allows a user to post on behalf of someone else... just for fun. It's a node function that lives in AWS Lambda.

By typing `/mybot danturcotte^ hello` I get in Slack:

[image]

The annoying thing is each time I post, my Slackbot, "Dante", replies.

When I `postToSlack`, I tried these two options to ensure my bot won't follow up with the slack posting:

```
1) context.succeed();

2) callback(error, null);
```

Both ways still have Dante respond with `null`. How can I simply only post the incoming webhook and nothing else (aka, danturcotte saying hello)?

AWS Lambda NodeJS code snippet:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var qs = require('querystring');
var request = require('request');

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {

    var params = qs.parse(event.postBody);

    var botPayload = {};
    botPayload.channel = params.channel_name;

    if (typeof params.text !== 'undefined') {

        botPayload.userToGet = params.text.split('^')[0];

        getUserData(botPayload, function (error, status, body) {

            var userDataArray = JSON.parse(body),
                profileFound = false;

            for (var i = 0; i < userDataArray.members.length; i++) {
                if (!profileFound) {
                    if (userDataArray.members[i].name === botPayload.userToGet) {
                        //set bot to user
                    }
                }
            }

            postToSlack(botPayload, function (error, status, body) {
                //context.succeed();
                callback(error, null);
            });
        });
    }
};


function getUserData (payload, callback) {
    request({
        uri: 'https://slack.com/api/users.list?token=mytoken',
        method: 'GET'
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        callback(error, response.statusCode, body);
    });
};

function postToSlack (payload, callback) {

    var incoming_webhook = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T02LHM7GA/B11BS608F';

    request({
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        uri: incoming_webhook,
        body: JSON.stringify(payload),
        method: 'POST'
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            return callback(error);
        }
        callback(null, response.statusCode, body);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is possible with just Lambda and Slack. The [Slack slash command documentation](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands) says:

> If your command doesn't need to post anything back (either privately
> or publicly), respond with an empty HTTP 200 response.

So your goal is to have your Lambda function result in an HTTP response with no body. Unfortunately, per [the AWS Lambda documentation for Node.js](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html), it looks like all HTTP responses are JSON:

> The result provided must be JSON.stringify compatible. If an error is provided, this parameter is ignored.
>
> If you don't use callback in your code, AWS Lambda will call it implicitly and the return value is null.

So no matter what you do, your function is going to respond with some sort of JSON, and there's no JSON you can send back to Slack that will result in no message being displayed. (A `null` will display `null`, an empty string will come back as `""`, and `{"text": ""}` results in a `no_text` error.)

I believe you'll need some layer sitting in front of AWS Lambda that results in returning an empty body. It sounds like AWS API Gateway is a possibility for this layer (see [mapping templates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html#models-mappings-mappings)), but I don't have any first-hand experience with it.

**UPDATE**

It looks like this can indeed be done via the AWS API Gateway. I got this working by creating a "Body Mapping Template" for `application/json` that maps to `$input.path('$')`. This means that you can pass an empty string (`""`) to `callback` to result in no response body at all. (If you *do* want to respond in some way, just make sure to return a string.)

Comment: I am having this exact problem, but the AWS console is less than user friendly.  Can you detail a bit more about how you create a Body Mapping template in the API gateway console?

Comment: This UPDATE worked for me. One clarifying note for others, the entire mapping is just the _$input.path('$')_ line, and you put it in the _Integration Response_ section.